# TinyMce - Cannot read property 'add' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, onchange, tinymce-4

Official page tinymce for event `onChange` [**here**](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:event.tinymce.Editor.onChange)

```
<script>
    tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    language: "ru",
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link charmap anchor",
        "searchreplace fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime paste"
    ],
    toolbar: "undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link",
    setup : function(ed) {
        ed.onChange.add(function(ed, l) {
            console.debug('Editor contents was modified. Contents: ' + l.content);
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

i use this code but tinymce not working and in console i see error `Cannot read property 'add' of undefined`...

Tell me please why code not working nd how will be right ?

Answer (score 7):

The function for the onChange event that you have works with TinyMCE 3.x version
If you are working with TinyMCE 4.x version, the onChange function has this form:

```
tinymce.init({
    ...
    setup: function(editor) {
        editor.on('change', function(e) {
            console.log('change event', e);
        });
    }
});
```

You can see this function in the Oficial Page [here](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/events/#change).

Comment: i'm getting this error `tinymce editor error cannot read property doc is undefined` can you suggest me. code `var body = tinymce activeEditor.dom.doc.body`